# 4o4 not found in cakephp controllers

Tags: php, linux, cakephp

I have a CakePhp project placed in var/www/html/manage/

Manage folder contains (on ls)

```
CONTRIBUTING.md  app               build.xml      email      index.php  plugins
README.md        build.properties  composer.json  email.zip  lib        vendors
```

When i do http://domain/manage/

it gives me error, which is fine

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>
        CakePHP: the rapid development php framework:
        Errors  </title>
        <link href="/manage/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" />
        <link href="/manage/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/manage/css/cake.generic.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <h1>
                    <a href="http://cakephp.org">CakePHP: the rapid development php framework</a>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <h2>Missing Controller</h2>
                <p class="error">
                    <strong>Error: </strong>
                    <em>Controller</em> could not be found.
                </p>
                <p class="error">
                    <strong>Error: </strong>
    Create the class
                    <em>Controller</em> below in file: app/Controller/Controller.php
                </p>
                <pre>
&lt;?php
class Controller extends AppController {
```

I have a controller placed in app/Controller/

However when i try to do

```
http://domain/manage/users/registerAccount
```

Its giving me 404 not found error.

What am i missing

Comment: in the error.log there should be a more detailed error output. Also if 404 is given your debug is set to false in app.php probably. Orelse you would be given a more detailed error. If you have a UsersController with a registerAccount method, the default url would be users/register-account

Comment: @Tolga the url is correct, i copied the code

Comment: How do you mean it is correct? If you did not set upa custom route for http://domain/manage/users/registerAccount then it is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Ah ill make it an answer:
 Url by default wold be
 **http://domain/manage/users/register-account** in cakephp3